# Creating a multidimentional array result from a single mysql query

Tags: mysql, multidimensional-array

I have researched about this for days now and I can't seem to find the right query for me.

**Tables**

**1. Projects**

- id
- projectname
- date

**2. Notes**

- noteid
- note
- projectid

**Wanted Result:**

```
array =>
    project1 =>
        Notes1
        Notes2
        Notes3

    project2 =>
        Notes1
        Notes2
    project3 =>
    ….........
```

I am struggling to create a single query that will populate the result i wanted - Select all fields from **projects** and create another array for each id to hold all results that match project.id on notes.projectid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use what ever language your using to organize the array for you.

The SQL query you want to use is:

```
SELECT projects.*, notes.noteid, notes.note
FROM projects LEFT JOIN notes ON
    projects.id = notes.projectid
LIMIT 250;
```

Use a limit so you don't end up with a huge dataset. You can set the limit to whatever suits your needs or omit it if you are sure you don't need to wory about dataset size.

This will return a dataset like this:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
| id       | projectname | date     | noteid   | note     |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        | Project1    | 1/1/2000 | 1        | Notes1   |
| 1        | Project1    | 1/2/2000 | 2        | Notes2   |
| 1        | Project1    | 1/3/2000 | 3        | Notes3   |
| 2        | Project2    | 1/4/2000 | 4        | Notes1   |
| 2        | Project2    | 1/5/2000 | 5        | Notes2   |
| 3        | Project3    | 1/6/2000 | NULL     | NULL     |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I used a `LEFT JOIN` for the instances that a project doesn't have any notes yet. You can see what the results would look like for `Project3`. Then its up to your programming language to organize your dataset. Without knowing the limitations for your language, I don't want to theorize too much about how to organize this.